# Linear programming algorithm and equally share with Python PuLP

Tags: python, linear-programming, pulp

I have a variable named total_fuel_available which contains total amount of fuel available.

I have a list of zone object and each zone object contains 2 attributes :

- the first is local_fuel_limit which indicate the maximum fuel that the zone can accept
- the second is a list of one or many station object.

All station object has a min_fuel_acceptable and max_fuel_acceptable attribute that indicate the quantity of fuel that the station can accept and a last attribute (initialized to None) that contain the fuel quantity affected.

I want to write an algorithm that share as equally as possible the total fuel available to each station with station min and max constraint and without exceed the zone local_fuel_limit.

Here is my code :

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from pulp import *


class Station(object):

    def __init__(self, station_number, fuel_limit_min, fuel_limit_max):
        self.identity = "Station_%s" % station_number
        self.fuel_limit_min = fuel_limit_min
        self.fuel_limit_max = fuel_limit_max
        self.fuel_affected = None


class Zone(object):

    def __init__(self, fuel_limit, affected_stations):
        self.local_fuel_limit = fuel_limit
        self.stations = affected_stations


# Total fuel unit available for all zones
total_fuel_available = 96

zones = [
    # Zone 1 can't provide more than 32 fuel unit and has 3 stations
    Zone(32, [
        # Station 1 fuel unit required is 6 < x < 16
        Station(1, 6, 16),
        # Station 2 fuel unit required is 6 < x < 32
        Station(2, 6, 32),
        # Station 3 fuel unit required is 6 < x < 32
        Station(3, 6, 32),
    ]),
    # Zone 2 can't provide more than 32 fuel unit and has 3 stations
    Zone(32, [
        # Station 4 fuel unit required is 6 < x < 16
        Station(4, 6, 16),
        # Station 5 fuel unit required is 6 < x < 32
        Station(5, 6, 32),
    ]),
    # Zone 3 can't provide more than 32 fuel unit and has 6 stations
    Zone(32, [
        # Station 6 fuel unit required is 6 < x < 16
        Station(6, 6, 16),
        # Station 7 fuel unit required is 6 < x < 16
        Station(7, 6, 16),
        # Station 7 fuel unit required is 6 < x < 16
        Station(8, 6, 16),
        # Station 7 fuel unit required is 6 < x < 16
        Station(9, 6, 16),
        # Station 7 fuel unit required is 6 < x < 16
        Station(10, 6, 16),
        # Station 7 fuel unit required is 6 < x < 16
        Station(11, 6, 16),
    ]),
]

# create a flat dict with all station with identity (an uniq string) as key
stations = {}
for zone in zones:
    for station in zone.stations:
        stations[station.identity] = station

# Create the pulp problem
model = LpProblem("Fuel Distribution Model")

# Create a dict of LpVariable for each station (key is station identity)
# Variable will store the fuel unit affected to the station
station_fuel_affected = LpVariable.dicts("stations", stations.keys(), lowBound=0, cat='Integer')

# For each station
for station in stations.values():
    # Create constraint to specify that fuel affected need to be lower than station fuel_limit_max attribute
    model += station_fuel_affected[station.identity] <= station.fuel_limit_max
    # Create constraint to specify that fuel affected need to be upper more station fuel_limit_min attribute
    model += station_fuel_affected[station.identity] >= station.fuel_limit_min

# For each zone
for zone in zones:
    # Create constraint to specify that the sum of station affected fuel units is lower than zone local_fuel_limit
    model += sum(station_fuel_affected[station.identity] for station in zone.stations) <= zone.local_fuel_limit
    # Create a constraint to maximise the fuel affected to each stations
    model += zone.local_fuel_limit - sum(station_fuel_affected[station.identity] for station in zone.stations) == 0

# Create a constraint to specify that fuel affected to all stations need to be lower than total fuel available
model += sum(station_fuel_affected[station.identity] for station in stations.values()) <= total_fuel_available

# Create a constraint to maximise fuel affected to station
model += total_fuel_available - sum(station_fuel_affected[station.identity] for station in stations.values()) >= 0

# solve problem
status = model.solve()

# Display status
print("Status: %s" % LpStatus[status])

# Display result
for identity, var in station_fuel_affected.items():
    stations[identity].fuel_affected = var.value()
    print("Station '%s' affected fuel is %s" % (identity, stations[identity].fuel_affected))
```

Output :

```
Status: Infeasible
Station 'Station_1' affected fuel is 16.0
Station 'Station_2' affected fuel is 10.0
Station 'Station_3' affected fuel is 6.0
Station 'Station_4' affected fuel is 16.0
Station 'Station_5' affected fuel is 16.0
Station 'Station_6' affected fuel is 6.0
Station 'Station_7' affected fuel is 6.0
Station 'Station_8' affected fuel is 6.0
Station 'Station_9' affected fuel is 6.0
Station 'Station_10' affected fuel is 2.0
Station 'Station_11' affected fuel is 6.0
```

Output expected :

```
Status: Infeasible
Station 'Station_1' affected fuel is 10.6
Station 'Station_2' affected fuel is 10.6
Station 'Station_3' affected fuel is 10.6
Station 'Station_4' affected fuel is 16.0
Station 'Station_5' affected fuel is 16.0
Station 'Station_6' affected fuel is 6.4
Station 'Station_7' affected fuel is 6.4
Station 'Station_8' affected fuel is 6.4
Station 'Station_9' affected fuel is 6.4
Station 'Station_10' affected fuel is 6.4
Station 'Station_11' affected fuel is 0
```

Comment: Note that `6 > x > 16` means that x is less than 6 and greater than 16. That would make things infeasible.

Comment: You also should do something about `Status: Infeasible`. This is not a feasible solution.

Comment: The status is Infeasible because constraint ```station_fuel_affected[station.identity] >= station.fuel_limit_min``` can't be verified for last zone. I want to find the best sharing in order to better satisfy the constraints.

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve the above problem, I have used Google-ORtool's CP-SAT solver (python API). I am not well versed with PuLP, but hopefully you can formulate the problem in similar manner as below in PuLP.
A few callouts:

1. CP-SAT is an integer solver, i.e. it cannot handle floats. So I have used scaling factor to circumvent this problem
2. Objective function is to minimize total absolute deviation of each station-zone allocation from their respective zonal average. This will ensure an equitable distribution across stations within a zone
3. With current data, your problem is infeasible. To avoid infeasibility,
   I have changed `Station(11, 6, 16)` to `Station(11, 0, 16)`

Solution:

```
(zone, station) --> allocation

(0, 0) --> 10.66666
(0, 1) --> 10.66666
(0, 2) --> 10.66668
(1, 0) --> 16.0
(1, 1) --> 16.0
(2, 0) --> 6.0
(2, 1) --> 6.0
(2, 2) --> 6.0
(2, 3) --> 6.0
(2, 4) --> 6.0
(2, 5) --> 2.0
```

```
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model as cp

class Station(object):

    def __init__(self, station_number, fuel_limit_min, fuel_limit_max):
        self.identity = "Station_%s" % station_number
        self.fuel_limit_min = fuel_limit_min
        self.fuel_limit_max = fuel_limit_max
        self.fuel_affected = None


class Zone(object):

    def __init__(self, fuel_limit, affected_stations):
        self.local_fuel_limit = fuel_limit
        self.stations = affected_stations


# Total fuel unit available for all zones
total_fuel_available = 96

zones = [
    # Zone 1 can't provide more than 32 fuel unit and has 3 stations
    Zone(32, [
        # Station 1 fuel unit required is 6 < x < 16
        Station(1, 6, 16),
        # Station 2 fuel unit required is 6 < x < 32
        Station(2, 6, 32),
        # Station 3 fuel unit required is 6 < x < 32
        Station(3, 6, 32),
    ]),
    # Zone 2 can't provide more than 32 fuel unit and has 3 stations
    Zone(32, [
        # Station 4 fuel unit required is 6 < x < 16
        Station(4, 6, 16),
        # Station 5 fuel unit required is 6 < x < 32
        Station(5, 6, 32),
    ]),
    # Zone 3 can't provide more than 32 fuel unit and has 6 stations
    Zone(32, [
        # Station 6 fuel unit required is 6 < x < 16
        Station(6, 6, 16),
        # Station 7 fuel unit required is 6 < x < 16
        Station(7, 6, 16),
        # Station 7 fuel unit required is 6 < x < 16
        Station(8, 6, 16),
        # Station 7 fuel unit required is 6 < x < 16
        Station(9, 6, 16),
        # Station 7 fuel unit required is 6 < x < 16
        Station(10, 6, 16),
        # Station 7 fuel unit required is 0 < x < 16
        Station(11, 0, 16), ## CHANGED HERE : REDUCED LOWER BOUND TO 0 , ELSE INFEASIBLE
    ]),
]

num_zones = len(zones)
scaling_factor = 100000 # higher the scaling factor, better numerical precision

# representing above information in a dictionary for ease of use later
# applying scaling factor
zone_dict = {}
for i in range(num_zones):
    zone_dict[i] = (len(zones[i].stations), zones[i].local_fuel_limit * scaling_factor, [j.fuel_limit_min * scaling_factor for j in zones[i].stations], [j.fuel_limit_max * scaling_factor for j in zones[i].stations])

model = cp.CpModel()
    
# decision variables : for each zone and for each station inside it how much to allocate
# putting the required lower and upper bounds as stated in the problem earlier
dv_zone_station = {}
for zn in zone_dict:
    for st in range(zone_dict[zn][0]):
        dv_zone_station[(zn, st)] = model.NewIntVar(zone_dict[zn][2][st], zone_dict[zn][3][st], "zone : " + str(zn) + " ; station : " +  str(st))
    
# constraint : for each zone, sum across all stations should be equal to zone capacity
for zn in zone_dict:
    model.Add(sum(dv_zone_station[(zn, st)] for st in range(zone_dict[zn][0])) == zone_dict[zn][1])
    


dv_zone_sum = {}
dv_zone_avg = {}

for zn in zone_dict:
    dv_zone_sum[zn] = model.NewIntVar(0, zone_dict[zn][1], "")
    dv_zone_avg[zn] = model.NewIntVar(0, zone_dict[zn][1], "")
    model.Add(dv_zone_sum[zn] == sum(dv_zone_station[(zn, st)] for st in range(zone_dict[zn][0])))
    # for each zone calculate the average allocation per station
    model.AddDivisionEquality(dv_zone_avg[zn], dv_zone_sum[zn], zone_dict[zn][0])

dv_zone_store_dev_from_avg_raw = {}
dv_zone_store_dev_from_avg_abs = {}
for zn in zone_dict:
    for st in range(zone_dict[zn][0]):
        dv_zone_store_dev_from_avg_raw[(zn, st)] = model.NewIntVar(- zone_dict[zn][1] * scaling_factor, zone_dict[zn][1] * scaling_factor, "")
        dv_zone_store_dev_from_avg_abs[(zn, st)] = model.NewIntVar(0, zone_dict[zn][1] * scaling_factor, "")
        # raw deviation of zone, station allocation from the overall zonal average
        model.Add(dv_zone_store_dev_from_avg_raw[(zn, st)] == dv_zone_station[(zn, st)] - dv_zone_avg[zn])
        # absolute deviation of zone, station allocation from the overall zonal average
        # we need to minimize below, i.e for each zone, station the allocation should be as close
        # as possible to the zonal average
        model.AddAbsEquality(dv_zone_store_dev_from_avg_abs[(zn, st)], dv_zone_store_dev_from_avg_raw[(zn, st)])

# objective function                             
dv_total_abs_deviation_from_zonal_avg = model.NewIntVar(0, 10000000000, "")
    
model.Add(dv_total_abs_deviation_from_zonal_avg == sum(dv_zone_store_dev_from_avg_abs[(zn, st)] for zn in zone_dict for st in range(zone_dict[zn][0])))
    
model.Minimize(dv_total_abs_deviation_from_zonal_avg)

solver = cp.CpSolver()
solver.Solve(model)

# objective function value
total_absolute_deviation_from_zonal_avg = solver.ObjectiveValue() / scaling_factor
avg_absolute_deviation_from_zonal_avg = total_absolute_deviation_from_zonal_avg / 11 # 11 stations in total

# inspecting decision variable values 
for zn in zone_dict:
    for st in range(zone_dict[zn][0]):
        print(str(((zn, st))) + " --> " + str(solver.Value(dv_zone_station[(zn, st)]) / scaling_factor))
```